# FormGroup still have controls although deleted dynamically

Tags: angular-forms, angular-validation

We have angular page with structure of Left bar (Say Component A), Main content (Say Component B)and right side bar (Say Component C).

Under Left bar , we have dynamically added custom controls. Custom control has say 2 textbox (with validations) and a button. There is button called "Delete" under each control so that that control would be deleted if clicked.

Right Side bar has button say "Save" . Once user clicks on it validation do get fired (if applicable) or saves data.

Issue: 
Lets Say I  have 5 controls on Left side bar. Lets say their names are ctrl01,ctrl02,ctrl03,ctrl04,ctrl05
When I click on delete button of ctrl02 , It gets Deleted. and then FormGroup has only 4 records ctrl01,ctrl03,ctrl04,ctrl05 and so is UI

However when I Delete ctrl03/ctrl04/ctrl05 the object are Deleted from UI but FormGroup still has ctrl01,ctrl02,ctrl03,ctrl04,ctrl05.

So, Application doesn't Save data for ctrl01 as Validation gets fired for controls which are deleted(ctrl03,ctrl04,ctrl05) but still part of FormGroup.

Please note this issue occurs only after Deleting 2nd and onwards controls .For First it works fine.

I also checked if Object holding all these records is properly updated or not after Deleting. It is updating properly. That's why UI shows correct number of Custom controls. Its just FormGroup which is causing this issue.